# SQL Server Ordery By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have data in below format in SQL Server Table. Data Type of columns is nVarchar

```
(File # 1) abcde
(File # 3) abdddd
(File # 4) asdfas
(File # 7) ououoiu
(File # 6) ooiuoi
(File # 5) werwer
(File # 2) oiouoiu
(File # 10) xcvzx
(File # 11) cxzvz
(File # 20) zxcvzx and so on....
```

when i use order by clause on above mentioned column i get the result like below...

```
(File # 1) abcde
(File # 10) xcvzx
(File # 11) cxzvz
(File # 2) oiouoiu
(File # 20) zxcvzx
(File # 3) abdddd
(File # 4) asdfas
(File # 5) werwer
(File # 6) ooiuoi
(File # 7) ououoiu
```

How to Fix....

Comment: What collation are you using for those columns?

Comment: You say `columns` *(plural)*, but only seem to show one column?  What order do you want?  Can you ***guarantee*** that the part of the string you want to use in the ordering is always there and of the format you expect?  For example, if you want to order by file number, is there always a `#` and then a space and then a numeric value, terminated by a `)`.  Or, might there sometimes be no space, ot sometimes the numeric value accidentally contain letters?  etc, etc, etc.

Comment: nothing fixed here... it all changes according to user input. and its one column only... other one is unique id for every row..

Comment: Edward.. am using no collation...

Comment: If nothing is fixed, and it's truly free-form text, then you're going to struggle.  If they start adding leading 0's, then the necessary rules change.  If they stop using the space after the `#`, then the rules change.  If they start using letter instead of numbers, then the rules change.  You need to specify at least a working set of assumptions you can reasonably make.  But there is no universally robust fix to this, for that you need to stop allowing free-form text...

Comment: It is unlikely (impossible?) that there is no collation being used. The collation is a column attribute. You can find it by running the `sp_help` procedure calling the `table` in question.

Comment: @Edward... its Arabic_CI_AS... my mistake...

Comment: Do you want to sort by the file number (#20), or by the text (abcde)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's always the same format `(file # .....)` there's a simple solution:

```
order by charindex(')', col), col
```

Edit:

This extracts the *first group of digits* and casts it as an INT

```
ORDER BY
    CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col) > 0
              THEN SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(col,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col),100), 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(col,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col),100)+'#')-1) 
              ELSE '0'
          END AS FLOAT)
    ,col
```

Would be much easier if SQL Server supported Regular Expressions :-)

Comment: Elegant.  I hope the OP tests the assumption robustly, so as not to get messed around by double spaces or leading zeros :(

Comment: Feels like the name of that function should be `position` as it would fit more with `SQL Server` naming style. `charindex` could also get confusing with there being permanent `indexes` on `tables`.

Comment: @Shahid: If it's not fixed, then which variations do exist?

Comment: @Edward: There's no `position` in SQL Server, it's Standard SQL.

Comment: @edward : `CHARINDEX()` is the name of a function present in SQL Server.  There is no option to change its name here.

Comment: @dnoeth, It can be like below format also... January 2018 SOW, Project / Site Office, February 2018 SOW, March 2018 SOW, May 2018 SOW.. Original SOW.... and so on...

Comment: @dnoeth I know, I saw that you used `position` in your first edit. I think it made more sense given the naming conventions, but, yes, the correct function is `charindex()`

Comment: @Shahid: why did you show such simplified data in your question? You want to sort by the extracted first group of digits?

Comment: @dnoeth... i showed this list simple list because right now user is more concerned about this list... there are nearly 200 entries in the same format i showed... so its difficult for user to find required one... other entries are also there as i mentioned later.

Comment: I tried to use charindex but still some entries are out of order where there is space missing...

Comment: It may help, as other comments have suggested, that you give explicit rules for how you would want that column to be ordered. Then we could construct the logic that would implement those rules. Is the first ordering in your question also your desired output?

Comment: @dnoeth... your second solution worked excellent except for these three values... i tried to check but can't figured out whats the issue..  December 2016 , N/A and January 2017... error is Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Comment: @Shahid: This is because the string ends after the digits. I edited my answer to avoid this error.